# BibTex not citing one particular entry in et al. format

Tags: bibliographies, citing, harvard-style

The entry in the bib file is:

```
@article{singhsetal2003,
  title={On the use of modified randomization device for estimating the prevalence of a sensitive attribute},
  author={Singh, S and Horn, S and Singh, R and Mangat, NS},
  journal={Statistics in transition},
  volume={6},
  number={4},
  pages={515--522},
  year={2003}
}
```

I am citing it as `\cite{singhsetal2003}` which produces the citation Singh, Horn, Singh and Mangat (2003) instead of Singh et al. (2003), as intended. The other citations are correctly produced with et al.

Any idea what is wrong here?

ETA: I'm using

```
\catcode`'=9
\catcode``=9
\bibliography{bib2022}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
```

ETA: I am using TexLive 2023 with TexStudio editor. Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\cite{singhsetal2021}
\bibliography{bib2022}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us which citation management package, if any, you employ.

Comment: Please don't show only a code snippet, but show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) that could be used to reproduce the issue without guessing. You should start with `\documentclass` add all needed package and preamble code (but try to really only show the needed parts), have a `\begin{document}` and some body to produce the shown screenshot, and end with `\end{document}`. This would really help us, to help you.

Answer (score 0):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I am *unable* to replicate the issue you say you're experiencing if I load either the `natbib` or the `har2nat` citation management package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

% create a test bib file "on the fly":
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{singhsetal2003,
  title   = {On the use of modified randomization device for 
             estimating the prevalence of a sensitive attribute},
  author  = {Singh, S and Horn, S and Singh, R and Mangat, NS},
  journal = {Statistics in Transition},
  volume  = {6},
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {515--522},
  year    = {2003}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\begin{document}
\citet{singhsetal2003}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```